# How can I use easyPeasy's useStoreState in Storybook?

Tags: storybook, easy-peasy

I want to create a story in storybook for my component that uses a state from easyPeasy.

`const label = useStoreState((state) => state.localeModel.getLabel)`

When I try to create the story I am getting an error in storybook *An error occurred trying to map state in a useStoreState hook: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined*.
.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [`decorator`](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators) to wrap the `Story` with a `StoreProvider`.

It might look something like this:

```
// YourComponent.stories.js|jsx

import { StoreProvider } from 'easy-peasy';
import { store } from './store';

import { YourComponent } from './YourComponent';

export default {
  title: 'YourComponent',
  component: YourComponent,
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <StoreProvider store={store}>
        <Story />
      </StoreProvider>
    ),
  ],
};
```